# Woocommerce API Show orders updated after a certain date

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm looking for a way to get a list of orders that are updated after a certain  specified date. I'm using the Woocommerce REST API to access these orders. In the API docs I find there is a 'after' parameter on a GET call, but this only filters for orders published after a certain date, not updated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**
Add the following code in a custom plugin.

```
function modify_orders_after_query($request) {
    $request['date_query'][0]['column'] = 'post_modified';
    return $request;
}

add_filter( "woocommerce_rest_shop_order_query", 'modify_orders_after_query' );
```

Then you can make GET request to your API url, Something like this:
`http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?after=2016-10-10T10:10:10Z`

Notice: Please test before using this method.

**Legacy:**
This can be achieved with `updated_at_min`.
Please check `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\api\class-wc-api-resource.php`: `Line 157` and `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\api\class-wc-api-orders.php`: `Line 723`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only find these files in the legacy/v1-2-3 maps, not in the files using the REST API. Any clue how to achieve this using this latest REST API?

Comment: @Axel Sorry I was using v3 and gave answer for that. Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: thanks for the update. Should I include this code in the class-wc-rest-orders-controller.php file? And what would the API call look like?

Comment: @Axel No. If you edit woocommerce file, it will be replaced when you update wc next time. So create new plugin [like in this link](http://pastebin.com/xCqyWnyu). activate it. Then use the query. I Updated answer for "How api call look like".

Comment: @Karthik, How would I go about doing the same thing for the customers?

Comment: @Karthik is this still true with API v2 ? (I actually tried but the filter isn't taken into account)

Comment: @Manumie in v2 the hook to use is not woocommerce_rest_shop_order_query , but woocommerce_rest_orders_prepare_object_query

Comment: Any chance we can do this with products and variations, this is, tag the date modified field so that the "after" query argument in the API would return them. I can only find this filter "woocommerce_rest_prepare_{$this->post_type}" which i believed would be "woocommerce_rest_prepare_product" for products and "woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_variation" for variations but i dont know if its the right place. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem using the tips from above. Added a folder with a file in plugin folder, with the same name and the following content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: wooCommerceFilter
 * Description: Change the ORDER API endpoint to consider date_modified.
 * Version: 1.0
 */

function modify_orders_after_query($request) {
    $request['date_query'][0]['column'] = 'post_modified';
    return $request;
}

add_filter( "woocommerce_rest_orders_prepare_object_query", 'modify_orders_after_query' );


?>
```